# Like button on each page

Tags: asp.net, facebook, dynamic, facebook-like

I have a like button on my main page (master page in asp.net).
I added a like button on each dynamic page.
When I try to enter the link:
http://www.friend.co.il/details.aspx?id=2321
to one of the dynamic page in face book developer page:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/
I get the same number of like as the total site number and not just a number for the specific page.

Any body know whats I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Facebook's URL Linter on your dynamic page's URL](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.friend.co.il%2Fdetails.aspx%3Fid%3D2321) shows that it has [Open Graph](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) tags that refer to your website's main page. As a result, Facebook thinks that the canonical URL for http://www.friend.co.il/details.aspx?id=2321 is http://www.friend.co.il/.

You should either remove the meta tags from your subpages, or construct them so that they properly represent the content on each page.

Comment: Hi Martey. Thanks! At least I've found the reason now.

Comment: I hope that you can help me a little more to understand this.
Since I have the tags in my masterpage, They are the same in each page. I thought about building them dynamically in each page. The question is: I have a facebook page for the site and I think its because I add the OG tags to my main page. If I change the OG tags for the current url in each dynamic page, wan't it create a problem on facebook?
Thanks alot for finding the first problem. Its helped a lot.

Comment: Based on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/#types, I think that if you make the og:type "article", the Like button will work properly, but Facebook will not create pages for each individual pet.

Comment: Thanks Martey! You help a lot. I think I will move all the OG tags from my masterpage to my defult.aspx page So then only in this page i will have OG tags in in all other page I will have only The like button itself. Thank again.

Comment: Hi  Martey, I just wanted to come back and tell you that your answer helped me alot. It solved my problem and all fine mow.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your og:url meta tag and also be sure to not include the Facebook javascript file multiple times like you are currently doing.